# Random error with Mongoose and Mongodb: Not authorized to execute command

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mlab

My app is running NodeJS 9.5.0 and mongoose 5.1.3 on a MongoDB at Mlab.  On occasion, I will get a `not authorized to execute command` and a simple restart of the node process fixes the issue.  Any ideas what could be causing this?

My connection string:

```
// import environmental variables from our variables.env file
require('dotenv').config({ path: 'variables.env' });

// Connect to our Database and handle any bad connections
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE);
```

And in my variables.env (user/pass/db numbers redacted):

`DATABASE=mongodb://<DBUSER>:<DBPASS>@ds0000-a0.mlab.com:0000,ds000000-a1.mlab.com:00000/app?replicaSet=rs-ds00000`

I can't seem to isolate what is randomly causing the authentication error.

Comment: Can you connect from the command line using the same variables?  https://docs.mongodb.com/tutorials/connect-to-mongodb-shell/

Comment: I was able to connect via MongoDB Compass using the same credentials.  The credentials are verified, just seems to not authenticate from time to time.  Would a shell login confirm something different? (DB is on MLab)

Answer (score 0):

Just random, huh. Perhaps add a callback or a promise and trap the error:

```
mongoose.connect(uri, options, function(error) {
  // Check error in initial connection. There is no 2nd param to the callback.
});

// Or using promises
mongoose.connect(uri, options).then(
  () => { /** ready to use. The `mongoose.connect()` promise resolves to 
  undefined. */ },
  err => { /** handle initial connection error */ }
);
```

Source: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

Comment: I know!  It's really bugging me.  Last time this happened was at 3am and I couldn't recover quickly.  I'm already handling a mongoose connection error as follows: `mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => { console.error(err.message)};`.  Could I create another for auth issues that restarts the node app?

Comment: What was the error that you got? You really should just be connecting to the database once when the app starts up. So, I'm not sure why you are connecting at random times. You can do a process.exit when the error occurs, and have the node server restarted using Forever automatically. https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

Comment: I'm actually only connecting once on startup.  The error was that the user wasn't authorized to execute the command, but prior to that (verified by reading logs at Mlab), all commands execute just fine.  It's almost as if mid-running, the user/pass for the database connection is changed...is that even possible?  I'll try that `process.exit` advice now, thank you!